# Why is the technology in Oblivion so old?

Tags: oblivion

In [Oblivion](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1483013/) there is a scene where Jack takes us to his Earthly getaway that only he knows about.

Some background on when this film takes place is approximately 2077 and the war with the scavs occurred in 2017.

This is a bad video of that scene:

In that scene we see electricity being used, but the light bulbs are incandescent light bulbs and he is playing music from a most likely 1980's vinyl record player.

What I can't understand is, if it was 2017 when war broke out, being that anything he finds seems to amount to not much. Should we have not seen a heap CD's or DVD's and CD player? Not vinyl records and for that matter a record player from the 1980's would be extremely difficult to come across in a war torn  Manhattan in 2017? Also, maybe fluorescent light bulbs or LED's (Especially if Jack wanted to save energy)

### What was the out of universe reason for all the old tech in 2017 Oblivion?

Comment: Because he likes _old_ memorabilia? Remember he also describes an old baseball game to Viki.

Comment: @Gallifreyan, yeah, I guessed that. But, I was wondering if the writers had a particular idea for that scene, b/c 2017 assciates with LED's ,ipods, smartphones etc. for playing music. Even CD's are old tech for 2013 the time it was made.

Comment: The record player at least could be explained by digital media being wiped by some sort of super EMP from the TET

Comment: @revenant, good call!!! I didn't think of that.

Comment: @revenant But CDs would still remain intact.

Comment: @Gallifreyan, Another good point.

Comment: I hear vinyl is making a comeback...

Comment: vinyl has its own unique sound, and many claim they can hear the difference between it and digital (and thus compressed) media. becasue of this some people just prefer it to digital media. Jack may be one of those people. considering what his job is a strong sense of nostalgia may be something they eve looked for when hiring.

Comment: @John, how did he find something so scarce in 2017?

Comment: 4.6 million new vinyl records were sold in 2012 (the last year I have numbers for) vinyl is fairly popular making up 6% of all music sales and rising. Vinyl is popular enough to hold a minority market for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @John, the 1980's record player. Not the vinyl, non of those record players were sold in 2012.

Comment: do they ever show the whole record player? From the clip you never see more than a small part of it.

Comment: It is much more probable to find something really old while scavenging. Raise hand anyone who has any cd-player stored in on a shelf in an attic (or garage or cellar) covered with old stuff? From my perspective finding old tech in working condition would be much more likely, as those would be the items usually on the bottom of the pile of other stuff in a cellar, thus better protected. And cd being a microprocessor tech is much more likely to fail with even mildly unfavorable conditions.

Comment: I have a 1987 vintage Technics turntable in the next room - attached to same vintage Technics amp and Wharfedale speakers. My 17 year old son sometimes buys vinyl records.

Comment: guesswork: since a vinyl player is electromechanical, it can more easily be repaired and made to work again. (plus the EMP aspect mentioned above, more likely to survive detonating nukes.

Vika did no hands-on work and therefore might not even notice that spare parts meant for drones had been repurposed for an analogue amplifier and vinyl turntable.